# Backbone save callbacks never hit

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone model:

```
define(function() {
  var ContactModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot: 'http://www.somedomain.com',

    defaults : {
       'name'  : null,
           'email': '',
           'phone': '',
    },

    validate: function(attrs) {

        var name_filter = /[a-zA-Z'.,-\s]+/;
        var email_filter    = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        var errors = [];

        if(attrs['name'].length<1){
            errors.push({input_tag: 'name', error: 'Please enter your First Name'});
        }

        if(attrs['phone']==='' && attrs['email']===''){
            //messages['name'] = 'You must include a phone number or email';
            errors.push({input_tag: 'phone', error: 'You must include a phone number or email'});
        }

        if(attrs['email']!==''){
            if (!email_filter.test(attrs.email)){         
                errors.push({input_tag: 'email', error: 'Please enter a valid email address'});
            }
        }


        if(errors.length > 0){
           return errors;
        }

    }
  });

  return ContactModel;
});
```

In my view, I set the attribute values like this:

```
        this.model.set({
            name:$('#name').val(),
            phone:$('#phone').val(),
            email:$('#email').val(),
        });
```

I do the validation, then save the model with:

```
        this.model.save({
            success: function(model){

                console.log('successfully saved and model is ');
                console.log(model);

            },
            error: function(){

                console.log('there was an error');

            }
        });
```

The model gets saved on the server, but success or error callbacks are never hit. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Worked after I changed to:

```
    this.model.save([], {
        success: function(model){

            console.log('successfully saved and model is ');
            console.log(model);

        },
        error: function(){

            console.log('there was an error');

        }
    });
```